# SelectedIndexChanged no carga asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto. Necesito que cargue ciudades, regiones y comunas, lo cual se carga por cada cambio que haga, en este caso para partir con un *dropdownlist* llamado `ddlRegion`. Mi problema es que cuando cambio de región no entra en el evento `SelectedIndexChange`. Este es el código.

YA TIENE LA PROPIEDAD AUTOPOSTBACK="TRUE".

ASPX:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <p>Región</p>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegion" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRegion_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

CS:

```
protected void ddlRegion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlCiudad.DataSource = CiudadBusiness.ObtenerCiudadesBusiness().Where(p => p.IdRegion == 1).ToList();
    ddlCiudad.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Si agregas un punto de interrupción tampoco funciona?

Comment: Si pero aun asi no entra en el evento, se va para el page_load de la master page y despues sigue su flujo normal pero no se detiene en el evento :(

Comment: pudiste resolverlo? estoy con la misma situacion, es decir, funciona, pero si te vas de la web y volves a los minutos, deja de responder hasta que una refresca la web y empieza de nuevo.